How exactly does a p-n junction operate when biased by current *not* voltage?
I'm trying to understand on the Fermi-level of the P-N junction, what happens when I bias a diode via an ideal current source ? I understand how the energy levels behave when biased via voltage source, but I need to develop a similar understanding to what happens when current is being forced through a p-n junction ?
I am looking for an explanation similar to the link below, but based on what happens when the source is a current source, not a voltage source.
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/pnjun2.html
Thanks in advance,

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The voltage and the current across a P-N junction are not independent of each other. If you need to understand the behavior in terms of voltage, then maybe it will help if you think of the current source as if it actually were a voltage source with a demon whose hand is always on the control knob, and who always and instantaneously adjusts the voltage as needed to force the desired amount of current to flow.

The answer of @ondas is not correct! See my comment there!

If you force a current through an (ideal) pn-junction diode with an ideal current source, you immediately obtain the corresponding voltage applied to the diode from the I-V characteristic of the diode. You just consider the current the independent and the voltage the dependent variable. Then, from this voltage, you get as usual the difference in (quasi-) Fermi-levels of the p- and n-side of the junction.

Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question :) Appreciate the explanation.

The answer of @ondas is not correct! See my comment there!

In the link you provide, there is the case you specificially are interested in: Forward biased conduction

A current source can be thought of as voltage sources with a series resistor. Therefore, the voltage bias required to change the fermi levels between the positive and negative-doped semiconductors would still be valid EDIT: Be set by the current source as a dependent variable of the independent current.
What the current source does in reality is providing a set level  to flow in the circuit. If you have only the diode and the voltage source, while you are changing the fermi levels, in practicality there is no element in the circuit that makes the current flow. For practical devices, there are parasitic resistances that will make the current flow, but practical devices are slightly away from your original question.
EDIT: Since it is not possible to delete accepted answers, I would rather change the statement to support what freecharly answered:

The statement I did was not considering that ideal independent time-invariant current sources would equivalently have the voltage as a dependent variable of the set current value (regardless of the resistor which can be obtained via Norton's theorem).
In this case, setting an ideal current level, you would have a current density $\vec J$ which is the current density of electrons and holes $\vec J = \vec J_e + \vec J_h$ which is the electron and hole current density, respectively.

Current density is related to the electric field by the equation $\vec J = \sigma \vec E$ where $\sigma$ is the electrical conductivity, with units:
[A/m$^2$] = [S/m * V/m]
From here you can deduce where the bias comes from in terms of the voltage, current and electric field: A current density yields an electric field due to the gradients in the conduction and valence band edges, which in turn have to be non-zero in order for current to flow through.
The electric field from the voltage source and the current source are therefore related by the current density and electric field relation, where the drift current from applying an electric field is a dependent variable of the current injected by the current source, or the voltage gradient by the voltage source.

Thevanin and Norton equivalent circuits are indeed taught for a reason.

I see what you are saying .. thanks for the response and the good explanation ..

Your statement, "A current source can be thought of as voltage sources with a series resistor." is correct, which follows from the equivalence of Norton's and Thevenin's circuit. But the question is for an "ideal current source", which has an infinite resistance parallel to the current source, with an  equivalent infinite Thevenin voltage and an  infinite series resistance  to obtain a finite current. This is definitely not the voltage bias of the diode. Also, for a not ideal current source, the Thevenin voltage would  not be the voltage bias of the diode. This answer is not correct!

I agree with your statement and I added some background related to semiconductor physics to support the idea and complement your comment based on the underlying physical process, if you have any comments those are also appreciated.

A little late, but I wanted to thank you and @freecharly . I like the specifically the semiconductor physics background part !
